# Embeding Google calendar with custom calendar colors

Tags: php, iframe, google-calendar-api

I've embeded a google calendar displaying multiple calendars in my website, but I want to have the calendars displaying in colors other than the default options.

The request URL contains a color parameter for each calendar, but doesn't seem to accept non default colors. (The rendered colors also don't seem to be the same as these)

Looking at the source; the colors for each event are defined by inline CSS, and do not appear to have class or ID attributes that could be used to style them via a CSS file.

I've tried using PHP to get the html of the calendar and then use string replace to change the colors (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/12521755#12521755)) which works, except it doesn't change the colors
The PHP file I'm using:

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&showPrint=0&showTabs=0&showTz=0&height=750&wkst=2&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=1.keswickscouts.org_5d750s21fh55t45nsh4i49co5g%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23691426&src=1.keswickscouts.org_k8ai784s6meu1eh71fk21etseg%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23182C57&src=1.keswickscouts.org_4omjhqh48ud1lkigino18dmid0%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%232F6309&src=06illa48gj7en6896jv32cm93c%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23125A12&src=1.keswickscouts.org_m6mb8idejtptmfkve9gm6latd8%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%236B3304&src=1.keswickscouts.org_5uaafulf65hrc4b64j3bfa6660%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%235229A3&src=1.keswickscouts.org_qudhcb0ii68u6b5mgs2ase200o%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23B1365F&ctz=Europe%2FLondon');

$content = str_replace('</title>','</title><base href="https://www.google.com/calendar/" />',$content);

$content = str_replace('B5515D','CC9966', $content); //ASU
$content = str_replace('536CA6','099FF', $content); //Beavers
$content = str_replace('7EC225','33CC00', $content); //Cubs
$content = str_replace('125A12','006990', $content); //Eden
$content = str_replace('194D14','999966', $content); //Explorers
$content = str_replace('8C66D9','4D2177', $content); //Group
$content = str_replace('E67399','006666', $content); //Scouts

echo $content;

?>
```

Any sugestions? Simpler would be better

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky because the Google calendar you link to loads its elements dynamically with javascript so there is nothing to be changed by the potential solution you post.

The HTML-only version of the calendar doesn't have the variety of colours you're looking for, so that won't work either.

Further complications arise because the javascript rebuilds the calendar's body when the user resizes or moves between months. So even if you get the colouring right for the page load, it may not stay the way you want it to.

One solution is to continue to import the calendar to a local page to avoid cross-site restrictions, then get things right on the page load and fight to keep them that way by continuously checking for changes. I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way:

**LOCAL CALENDAR PAGE: cal.php**

```
<?php
  $content=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&showPrint=0&showTabs=0&showTz=0&height=750&wkst=2&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&src=1.keswickscouts.org_5d750s21fh55t45nsh4i49co5g%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23691426&src=1.keswickscouts.org_k8ai784s6meu1eh71fk21etseg%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23182C57&src=1.keswickscouts.org_4omjhqh48ud1lkigino18dmid0%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%232F6309&src=06illa48gj7en6896jv32cm93c%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23125A12&src=1.keswickscouts.org_m6mb8idejtptmfkve9gm6latd8%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%236B3304&src=1.keswickscouts.org_5uaafulf65hrc4b64j3bfa6660%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%235229A3&src=1.keswickscouts.org_qudhcb0ii68u6b5mgs2ase200o%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23B1365F&ctz=Europe%2FLondon");
  $content = str_replace('</title>','</title><base href="https://www.google.com/calendar/" />',$content);
  print $content;
?>
```

**Calendar Display Page**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language='javascript'>
    var oldhtml;

    function swapcolors(oldcolor, newcolor){
      console.log("Searching for " + oldcolor);
      $('iframe#gcal').contents().find('.rb-n').filter(
        function() {
          console.log(this);
          console.log($(this).css('background-color'));
          console.log($(this).css('background-color')==oldcolor);
          return $(this).css('background-color')==oldcolor;
        }
      ).css({'background-color': newcolor});
    }

    function recolor(){
      swapcolors('rgb(83, 108, 166)', '#099FF'); //Beavers
      swapcolors('rgb(126, 194, 37)', '#000000'); //Cubs 33CC00
      swapcolors('rgb(181, 81, 93)', '#CC9966'); //ASU
      swapcolors('rgb(18, 90, 18)', '#006990'); //Eden
      swapcolors('rgb(25, 77, 20)', '#999966'); //Explorers
      swapcolors('rgb(140, 102, 217)', '#4D2177'); //Group
      swapcolors('rgb(230, 115, 153)', '#006666'); //Scouts
    }

    function keepcolored(){
      if( $('iframe#gcal').contents()!=oldhtml){
        recolor();
        oldhtml=$('iframe#gcal').contents();
      }
    }

    $(document).ready(
      function() {
        $('iframe#gcal').load(recolor);
        oldhtml=$('iframe#gcal').contents();
        window.setInterval(keepcolored, 700);
      }
    );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <iframe id="gcal" style="width:100%;height:100%" src="cal.php">
  </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that `find('.rb-n')` may need to be adjusted and that background colours are converted to RGB values (ala `rgb(230, 115, 153)`) before they are returned.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you using two arrays an only one str_replace :

```
$search = array('B5515D', '536CA6', '7EC225');
$replace = array('CC9966', '099FF', '33CC00');

$content = str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
```

A much more complicated advise would be to use the [google calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/get_started?hl=fr).

Comment: It's noticeably faster (thanks), but unfortunately still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hoping to avoid the complexity of an API-based approach, these days there are a number of third party apps that make it easy to style and embed Google calendars.

Here is a short list of options:

- [Styled Calendar](https://styledcalendar.com/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=forum-posts)
- [Tockify](https://tockify.com/i/docs/howto/googlesync)
- [ChronoFlo Calendar](https://www.chronoflocalendar.com/tutorials/entry/make-a-branded-version-of-your-google-calendar/)

Or, if you'd rather use something open source, [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) is a great solution. Here is some documentation on how to use their Google Calendar plugin: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar

- *Full disclosure, I'm a member of the [Styled Calendar](https://styledcalendar.com/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=forum-posts) team*